# How do I get rid of super glue marks?

Tags: adhesive

I was using Gorilla super glue ([this damn thing](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/gorilla-super-glue-brush-nozzle/)) to fix some chipped off furniture pieces and a loose rubber pad on a laptop. I think I used too much of it and made a little mess with spilled glue. I accidentally left some finger imprints on the laptop and furniture and the loose rubber strip was not aligned right. Is there a way to easily remove the marks? I tried scrubbing and it didn't seem to work. The most concerning marks are on my laptop front and back (I think the laptop case is aluminum with silver paint, not sure though).

Follow-up question: Can I use acetone on a laptop surface and on rubber?

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit your title into a different question.  See my comment - no one will be able to tell you for sure if acetone is safe on your particular laptop. _"Probably"_ or _"Maybe"_ is the best you're going to get.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I edited the title after being downvoted. I thought some people might've found the question to be dull and not showing enough research (which I admit). But part of my question is about how to remove the marks on specific materials. That is why I specified the things involved. So I edited the title to be more specific. But I get your point and reversed the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FAQ on the Gorilla Glue website:

> To remove uncured Gorilla Super Glue, use a towel dampened with acetone or isopropyl alcohol to blot the area. Several applications may be necessary to completely remove the uncured glue. For removal of cured Gorilla Super Glue from the surface of your project, soak bonded area with warm soapy water or acetone. The adhesive should begin to soften, but many applications may be necessary. Keep in mind that isopropyl alcohol and acetone can damage some surface materials, such as countertops and some plastics. Always test in a small, unseen area first.

Using Acetone or fingernail polish remover is a common suggesting for removing super glue type adhesives.  Of course, you need to make sure the surface you are removing it *from* will be safe from the acetone.

Comment: Thank you. I should have read the web page more thoroughly. I did read everything on the package but didn't see this. I guess my follow-up question is can I use acetone on a laptop and rubber?

Comment: Most "rubber" will be ok with acetone, but there are a lot of materials that fall under the term "rubber".  Even if I could see and feel the material, I would still say, "I don't know".  Testing a small area is your best bet.  It should be safe for a metal laptop, but even then if the metal is painted or has some type of sealer on it it could discolor.  Again, test a small area on the bottom or other less visible area.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove glue marks with acetone. Wipe the glue marks using a cloth with pure acetone or acetone for nail polish. Rub until the glue marks are gone.